# Validate Textbox Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is the following code, I am learning Javascript on my own and wanted to know how I could validate my code to make the textboxes say something like "please enter a value" or "please enter a valid Username or password.

I've attempted, but this is as far as online searching that I have done for it.

```
 <head>
       <script type = 'text/javascript'>
    function nullcheck()
      {
        if(document.getElementById("").value==="")
        {
          alert("Please enter value.");
          return false;
        }
      }
    </script> 
      <title>Login Form</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>

    </head>

    <body>
      <section class="container">
        <div class="login">
          <h1>Login</h1>
          <form method="post" action="index.xhtml">
            <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" id="Username or Email" /></p>
            <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="Password"/></p>
            <p class="remember_me">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me"/>
                Remember me on this computer
              </label>
            </p>
            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login" onchange="nullcheck()"/><button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button></p>

          </form>
        </div>

      </section>

    </body>

    </htm
```

Comment: Inputs support `onchange` events. Note that `id`s should not contain any spaces or special characters and be always lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate items one at a time, but a more general solution is to write a `validate()` function.  Make your form element look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="index.xhtml" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

If the `validate()` function returns false, the form will not be submitted.  It is up to the `validate()` function to issue prompts, etc.

Sample function:

```
function validate() {
var error = false,
    errmsg="";
    if(document.getElementById("username").value==="") {
       error = true;
       errmsg = "User name may not be blank.\n";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("password").value==="") {
       error = true;
       errmsg = "Password may not be blank.\n";
    }
    if (error) {
       alert(errmsg);
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
    }
} // validate
```

Comment: Put it in your HTML file where you now have nullcheck() and make sure the id= attributes in the form match those in `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: Don;t forget to use `<form method="post" action="index.xhtml" onsubmit="return validate();">` also.